# Is it possible to run in parallel an executable which has to read an input file with a fixed name in the current directory?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have an executable "myprog.exe" which reads the textfile "input.in" and give the output file "output.ov".
I would like to run this program in parallel using a matlab script and the parallel toolbox.

I have tried the following :

```
% open a 6-worker pool with 'write_input.m' as dependency
parpool(6,'AttachedFiles','write_input.m')

parfor ii = 1:100

    % write input.in with the ii-th parameter set
    write_input(ii); 

    % run myprog.exe for the ii-th parameter set
    runprog = which( 'prog.exe' );
    eval(['!"' runprog '" ']);

end % ..ii
```

But it doesn't work because there are conflicts when workers try to read/write "input.in" and I end up with an invalid file identifier error.

Then I would like to know if there is an obvious solution that i don't know or a workaround with this.

Last things:

- I don't have the source code of this executable ;
- the machine is working under Windows

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe you can run `prog.exe` with different copies of `input.in` in different working directories?

Comment: Wait, are you triying to write in the same file with different workers? Of course you cant do that! try to open any file in your computer and without closing it try to delete it! You cant! because someone else has the file opened. One, and only one process can write (modify) a file at a time. Reading should be OK though.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestions.Writing the same file with to different worker is indeed the issue that I was  trying to avoid.

Comment: Daniel's suggestion runs without crashing. 

Workers create their own temporary directory, move in it, and then each one has its own version of input.in in separate directories. No more conflict. After the process they go back in the initial directory and clean temporary one.

I haven't checked the outputs yet, to make sure everything is definitively ok though.

Comment: Ok, results look fine as well. Thanks!